# Graph Laplacian, requirements

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for a PSD matrix $S$, to be a graph Laplacian?
I know $S1=0$ is required.
But clearly a real zero sum PSD matrix is not necessarily a graph Laplacian.

Second question arises after seeing the useful responses here: What are the conditions for a PSD matrix to be a weighted graph Laplacian?

Comment: What is a PSD matrix?

Comment: Sorry, I meant positive semi-definite matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean positive-semidefinite for PSD, a graph laplacian has degrees of the graph on the diagonal, so we must have the [Erdos Gallai condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) for the degrees (that's necessary and sufficient for existance of the graph with given degree sequence). Other than that, the other entries must be either -1 or 0 with row and column sumbs equal to 0.

Comment: Depending on your setting it might be okay to use other off-diagonal entries than -1. For example you could build a Laplace matrix for a weighted graph, or a graph with parallel edges.

Comment: @ Alex: How is it possible that Erdos Gallai condition for degrees does not hold, when the off-diagonal elements are directly giving the adjacency matrix for the graph? Constraining values in set $\{-1,0\}$ prevents multi-edges. Perhaps we only need a symmetric matrix then?

Comment: @user25004: If I understand you correctly, you're saying, put in 0 and -1 entries making sure the matrix is positive definite, then make sure the diagonal is minus the sum along a row or column. Right, so you'd be specifying the graph. But you're asking for necessary and sufficient conditions right?

Comment: To be clear, take something like $$$$\begin{bmatrix} 3&-1 \\\\ -1&1  \end{bmatrix}$$ whose eigenvalues are all positive.

Comment: @Alex: For your example, the row-sums are not zero. What I want to claim is that any PSD matrix $S$, where $S_{ij}\in {-1, 0}$ and $S1= 0$ is a Laplacian matrix regardless of Erdos Gallai condition.  However, I think some of my conditions are redundant